# AWS RSD - C# .Net Core Entity framework - create table - Access denied

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, amazon-web-services

I would like to make data table via EF
I have AWS RSD ms sql database server running

when i run this "dotnet ef database update" i get this error:
"CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'."

I have checked the permissions, and my master user has rights to create any database table...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Only a SSQL Admin can create a master database.  You could create a dbo database instead.  Or you may not have the credentials to write to any database.  I always recommend using SQL Server Management Studio and see if you can login and perform queries before you start to do same with c# connection/entity.

Comment: I used SQL server management studio, and i could make a datatable or event database

Comment: I assume SSMS login window says Window Credential.  Then the c# connection string should have same server and  instance as the SSMS login window.  The connection string should also have Integrated Security = true which indicates you are using Windows credentials.   Following these steps c# should always work when SSMS works.  The only time it may fail if you are accessing the database through a service and the service is running with different credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The master database is a System database internal to SQL Server. You never need to run the CREATE TABLE command inside that database.

It looks like you're not in the right database context: you're running commands against that database rather than your own database.